# Why is RankX always returning a 1?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using the AdventureWorks2016 data warehouse database. I created a measure named 'Total Sales Rank', which can be seen below. I am simply trying to rank each product according to sales (internet sales). The 'Total Sales' column in the table below is a measure `(Sum([SalesAmount]))` which sums all sales. I cannot figure out why RankX is returning 1 for each product. There are no filters in place. All the tables are properly related.

By the way, there are other questions somewhat like this but different enough where the answers do not help this situation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ALL('Product') instead of just 'Product'.

Since you have products as filters (yes, you do!), for each row in your report RANKX "sees" only one record (for the product of the row). That's why you are getting "1"s. Instead, in each record you need to "see" the entire table, so that RANKX can compare multiple rows. This is accomplished by using ALL() function (or ALLSELECTED, etc).

This article might  help you further:
[Using RANKX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/use-of-rankx-in-power-bi-measures/)